# Can I make python __init__ method initDict refer to itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty sure the grammar used within my title is incorrect, hopefully my example will make more sense. Is the below code correct syntax?

```
class food:
    def __init__(self):
        initDict = {
            "fruit": ['apple', 'orange', 'blueberry'],
            "all_foods": "fruit" + ['broccoli','carrot']}

        self.Inputs = initDict
    def idk(self):
        print(self.Inputs['all_foods'])

f = food()
```

Basically, I am trying to make `all_foods` contain everything that's in `fruit` and add to the string.

I agree with and get the same error as @Thierry Lathuille:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Temp\2/ipykernel_18476/990716159.py", line 1, in <module>
    f = food()

  File "C:\Users\Temp\2/ipykernel_18476/3991279104.py", line 5, in __init__
    "all_foods": "fruit" + ['broccoli','carrot']}

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Why do you suspect it *isn't* correct syntax?

Comment: It's correct syntax (as you can easily check yourself) but it doesn't do what you want (as you can also easily check).

Comment: I get a `TypeError` when I try to create this `dict`.

Comment: `"fruit" + ['broccoli','carrot']` isn't valid, and rightly gives `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I receive the same error. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Note that there are barely any variables in that code – only `initDict` and `self`. Everything else are *literal* `dict`, `list` and `str`s. Getting these distinction right can help you gauge whether the code is even feasible to do what you want – for example, `"fruit" + [...]` attempts to add a string and a list and there is no way for it to represent "everything thats in fruit and add extra variables". This is also important to describe what you need: it is currently ambiguous whether `"fruit" + ...` should represent the *momentary* state or also include future updates.

Comment: @Axe319 That actually only returned 'fruit' and not everything within `fruit`

Comment: @worldCurrencies You're going to have to clarify a bit. `"fruit"` isn't just a string? Is it actually a variable? What type of variable?

Comment: @Axe319 Apologies, it is just a string. There are no variables. Will fix the wording

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. The question clearly has nothing to do with classes or `__init__` methods.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So what would it have to do with? I said in the beginning of my question that i am relatively new to python and to please correct my grammar if i am wrong. though somebody thought that detail was unimportant and edited it out of my original question

Comment: It has to do with the code that you want to use **to create the dictionary**. To figure this out, the question you should ask yourself is: "can I recreate this problem by just using the code for creating the dictionary, by itself?" and the way you answer this question is by **trying it**. This is explained in [mre], which is why I asked you to read it.

Comment: " though somebody thought that detail was unimportant and edited it out of my original question" Yes; this is **not a discussion forum**, and so we are not interested in your level of skill (it does not change the question, or how to answer it), and do not need to be invited to correct your grammar (people with editing privileges will do that without needing an invitation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW

```py
class food:
    def __init__(self):
        fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'blueberry']
        all_foods = fruits + ['broccoli','carrot']
        self.inputs = {
            "fruit": fruits,
            "all_foods": all_foods,
        }


    def idk(self):
        print(self.inputs["all_foods"])

f = food()
```